# PHP DOMDocument, finding specific elements

Tags: php, html, parsing, html-parsing, domdocument

I'm looking to find a specific attribute of a specific element in an HTML document using PHP DOMDocument.

Specifically, there is a div with a unique class set, and only a single span inside of it. I need to retrieve the style attribute of that span element.

Example:

```
<div class="uniqueClass"><span style="text-align: center;" /></div>
```

For this example, with the uniqueClass being the only instance of that class in the document, I would need to retrieve the string:

> text-align: center;

Comment: See question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571232/parse-html-with-phps-html-domdocument/22345590#22345590

Answer (score 4):

You have to use DOMXPAth class

```
$doc = new DOMDocument; 
// We don't want to bother with white spaces
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$doc->loadHTML($htmlSource);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

// We starts from the root element
$query = '//div[@class= uniqueClass]/span';

$entries = $xpath->query($query);

$spanStyle = $entries->current()->getAttribute('style')
```

Comment: Damn my slow typing, that's pretty much exactly the same solution I was going to suggest :)

Comment: Aha, "xpath".  I shall do the requisite research on that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);
$result = $xpath->evaluate('//div[@class=uniqueClass]/span/@style');
```