# Parse HTML with PHP's HTML DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, parsing, domdocument

I was trying to do it with "getElementsByTagName", but it wasn't working, I'm new to using DOMDocument to parse HTML, as I used to use regex until yesterday some kind fokes here told me that DOMEDocument would be better for the job, so I'm giving it a try :)

I google around for a while looking for some explains but didn't find anything that helped (not with the class anyway)

So I want to capture "Capture this text 1" and "Capture this text 2" and so on.

Doesn't look to hard, but I can't figure it out :(

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="text">
    Capture this text 1
    </div>
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div class="text">
    Capture this text 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you want to get :

- The text
- that's inside a `<div>` tag with `class="text"`
- that's, itself, inside a `<div>` with `class="main"`

I would say the easiest way is not to use [**`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) -- which will return all tags that have a specific name *(while you only want some of them)*.

Instead, I would use an XPath query on your document, using the [**`DOMXpath`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) class.

For example, something like this should do, to load the HTML string into a DOM object, and instance the `DOMXpath` class :

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div class="main">
    <div class="text">
    Capture this text 1
    </div>
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div class="text">
    Capture this text 2
    </div>
</div>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
```

And, then, you can use XPath queries, with the [**`DOMXPath::query`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) method, that returns the list of elements you were searching for :

```
$tags = $xpath->query('//div[@class="main"]/div[@class="text"]');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    var_dump(trim($tag->nodeValue));
}
```

And executing this gives me the following output :

```
string 'Capture this text 1' (length=19)
string 'Capture this text 2' (length=19)
```

Comment: Oh, no wonder google didn't find anything, was looking the wrong thing up. Thats exactly that I needed. I was also wonder of a good way to get test HTML code into a string, but looks like you read my mind and answered that too, thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome :-) Well, the more I use DOM, the more I love it ;-) Have fun !

Comment: @PascalMARTIN correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't `DOMDocument->loadHTML()` expect a real HTML document, html, head, body tags and all?

Comment: @Christian it can load not well-formed HTML *(and works with portions of HTML strings, with no html/body/... tags)*

Comment: @PascalMARTIN My bad! That's very useful to know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

It is very simple easy to use DOM parser written in php, by which you can easily fetch the content of div tag.

Something like this:

```
// Find all <div> which have attribute id=text
$ret = $html->find('div[id=text]');
```

See the documentation of it for more help.