# PHP get entire HTML DOM incl. tags

Tags: php, html, dom

how can I extract the whole html dom element incl. tags via php?
eg. for:

```
<table id="tab">
    <tr>
        <td>
            foo
        </td>
        <td>
            bar
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

i do not want only "foo bar" but the whole "`<table id="tab"><tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr></table>`" basically, i need a way (funciton) to get the whole tag with inner tags and content via it's id.
Something like getTagViaID('http://www.foo.com', 'bar') -> where 'http://www.foo.com' is the link to the page and 'bar' is the id.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may also want to check out the DOMDocument class provided by PHP:

http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

That'll get the html file loaded

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php

That'll parse through the HTML file looking for things based on tags. That should get you started. There's additional discussion about getting tag info in this post.

[PHP's DOMXPath is stripping out my tags inside the matched text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574625/phps-domxpath-is-stripping-out-my-tags-inside-the-matched-text)

Hope you get it working!