# Parsing XML tag using PHP DOM - XPATH without losing inside tags and data

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath

I want to parse data which looks similar to the following:

```
<table-wrap id ="T1">
<table-wrap-foot>
<fn>
<p>
Blah blah blah <strong>dsf</strong> blah blah blah <br>
</p>
</fn>
<table-wrap-foot>
<table-wrap>
```

When I call

```
$x = $xpath->query("//table-wrap-foot[@id='" . $tableAttributes . "']/p")->item(0);
```

I'll get the node of paragraph including tags and data inside along with the `<p>` tags.

```
$x = $xpath->query("//table-wrap-foot[@id='".$tableAttributes."']/p")->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

I'll get the data inside the

tags but it doesn't contain `<strong>` tag..

So my requirement is I need data along with tags inside excluding the `<p>` tags.

Is there any possibility to do that?

Comment: So my requirement is I need data along with tags inside excluding the <p> tags.

Comment: possible duplicate of [innerHTML in PHP's DomDocument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument)

Comment: Yea.. Its similar and it solved the issue.. Thanks for letting me know about the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply select the `node()` children of your `p` element and iterate the list. Taking your example expression at face value (although it doesn't match up to your sample input):

```
//table-wrap-foot[@id='".$tableAttributes."']/p/node()
```

Note that there are five such nodes:

```
#text 
strong
#text 
br
#text
```

Even more appropriate would be to select the union of these text and element nodes:

```
//table-wrap-foot[@id='".$tableAttributes."']/p/*|
//table-wrap-foot[@id='".$tableAttributes."']/p/text()
```

Comment: Even this article helps.. and solves my problem... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574625/phps-domxpath-is-stripping-out-my-tags-inside-the-matched-text

Comment: lwburk : Your solution is perfect.. Used the node() to access each node inside and using a loop attached those nodes to the HTML... Thanks a Lot..