# Extract element from html source code with xpath scripting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xpath

Here I have a some HTML code and I need to 1st. load url source code then type xpath and as a result get a some text from that URL based on xPath... How to do that... with jquery, ajax ... ???

http://jsfiddle.net/cHtWq/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<label>Enter URL address here: 
<input name="textfield" type="text" value="http://www." />
</label>
<label>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
<br />
<br />
Enter xpath location of element:
<input type="text" name="textfield2" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit2" value="Submit" />
<br />
<br />
Selected element is: </label>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: something like xpath extractor ...

Comment: Yes I can becouse I first load source code from some URL...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in JavaScript because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) you will need some back end scripting to do this.

Comment: I think it can be possiblle with ajax

Comment: 1st load source code when I type URL and click on submit then I write a xpath location and as a result get a text

Comment: @MikiCloud AJAX isn't magic ... it has to adhere to the the same security policy ... you can do cross domain AJAX but using JSONP only ...

Comment: Ok how I can do that with JSON?

Comment: please Help and I will appreciate to donate some money on your paypal account HELP!

Comment: JSON will not help you here - what you need is a backend script - PHP for example would be able to do this very easily ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571232/parse-html-with-phps-html-domdocument

Comment: What are you trying to find on a remote site ?

Comment: yes I have that php file for parse html but NOW i need to combine php file and the second file above to get script... but How to do that... json, how to connect this two files

Comment: I try to get some text based on my xpath

Comment: Have a look at this question / answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571232/parse-html-with-phps-html-domdocument its exactly what you want to do ...