# PHP - grabbing text between html tags (screen scraping)

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

I have looked around stackoverflow pretty extensively and cannot find exactly what I'm looking for.

I am trying to grab the text between two tags in an html doc. the problem is that the text length and content will change each time (we're screenscraping multiple pages) so I cannot set a substr length and cannot do it via regex.

is there an "end" equivalent to strpos?

the code I am using is:

```
$start = strpos($content,'<title>');
$end = strpos($content,'</title>');
$coName =substr ($content,$start,$end);
```

but it is returning far more than just what is between the title tags on the page.

Comment: What about using a DOM parser?

Comment: And here is one of the numerous questions like this that have answers with example code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571232/parse-html-with-phps-html-domdocument

Answer (score 0):

The third argument of `substr` is `length`, not `end`. So it should be `$end-$start`.