# How to export img urls from a html text

Tags: php, url

I have the following:

```
$input = '<p>This is a sample of a content I am working with <br /> Check out this image <img src="http://mydomain.com/1.png" /> or this one <img src="http://mydomain.com/2.png" />';
```

How can I get this two urls in an array?

```
['<img src="http://mydomain.com/1.png" />','<img src="http://mydomain.com/2.png" /'>]
```

Comment: Maybe you wanna use this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php And beware, you can too easily invite Zalgo by using some answers.

Comment: Zalgo? I don'tr know what you're talking about

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To parse HTML it is recommanded to use PHP's DOMDOCUMENT, as stated here:
[Parse HTML with PHP's HTML DOMDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571232/parse-html-with-phps-html-domdocument)

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($input);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
        echo $img->getAttribute('src') . "<br />\r\n";
    }
```

Comment: Could you add an example how it works with my $input var, please?

Answer (score 0):

This will probably helps you : http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0):

I think this function will be more suitable for your purpose:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Answer (score 0):

Simple! Check [HTMLSQL](https://github.com/hxseven/htmlSQL)

With HTMLSQL you can filter all html tags.

Comment: Looks interesting, but it seems a bit outdated. Also I am not allways fetching this values from database..

Comment: HTMLSQL is HTML parser, like DOMDOCUMENT!