# DOMXpath get from different classes

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath

i have something like this:

```
<div class='rand'>
    some text...
</div>
<div class='rand1'>
    some text..
</div>
<div class='rand2'>
    some text..
</div>
.
.
.
```

I want to take from all the different divs only those whose `class='rand'` or `class='rand2'`  all in one DOMXpath query..
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xpath:

```
//div[@class='rand' or @class='rand2']
```

Here are examples on how to run the xpath query:
[Parse HTML with PHP's HTML DOMDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571232/parse-html-with-phps-html-domdocument)

Comment: omg!! believe me i search for that before posting this! Also thanks for the link. Domxpath search in google sucks!