# preg_match between html tags

Tags: php, preg-match

I need to grab the names between the html tags.

```
<div class="from"><span class="profile fn">firstnamed familyname</span></div>
```

so far I tried according to examples from other poeple with the same question:

```
preg_match(";from"><span class="profile fn>(.?)</span></div>;", $text, $match)
```

but it doesn't work.

What is the correct way?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Explain "it doesn't work".

Comment: You should try parsing HTML with `DOMDocument` instead of regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571232/parse-html-with-phps-html-domdocument

Comment: You didn't escape the quotation marks within the preg_match call.

Comment: [Tony The Pony He Comes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/467164)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match(";from"><span class="profile fn>(.?)</span></div>;", $text, $match)
```

... should trigger this:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Apart from that:

- You seek for an unclosed attribute that's not in the original text:

  `class="profile fn` vs `class="profile fn"`
- You seek for zero or one characters:

  `.?`

Fixed regexp would be:

```
$text = '<div class="from"><span class="profile fn">firstnamed familyname</span></div>';
preg_match(';from"><span class="profile fn">(.*)</span></div>;', $text, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

Of course, this will probably break on large HTML documents (as soon as there's another `</span></div>` bit later on). Regular expressions are impossible to get right when used for parsing HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
preg_match(";from"><span class="profile fn>(.?)</span></div>;", $text, $match)
```

is syntactically incorrect, you have to escape the double quotes:

```
preg_match(";from\"><span class=\"profile fn>(.?)</span></div>;", $text, $match)
```

Comment: thanks. the code that Álvaro G. Vicario wrote worked without escape the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape special charcters (e.g. the quotes):

```
preg_match(";from\"><span class\=\"profile fn>(.?)</span></div>;", $text, $match)
```