# Get href value by id from html string

Tags: php, dom

I have a html string

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
bla bla bla <br />
<a id="downloadbutton" href ="http://tomtuoi.com/file.exe";
</body>
</html>
```

With php dom I want get http://tomtuoi.com/file.exe url by id. thank for help

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571232/parse-html-with-phps-html-domdocument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this..

```
<?php
$html='<html>
<head></head>
<body>
bla bla bla <br />
<a id="downloadbutton" href ="http://tomtuoi.com/file.exe";
</body>
</html>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $tag) {
    echo $tag->getAttribute('href'); //"prints" http://tomtuoi.com/file.exe
}
```

Comment: Mine ended up printing only from the root directory on so: file.exe. I had to prepend the http://domain.com to the output.