# regex to skip a tag if it is inside of another tag

Tags: php, html, regex

I would like to remove anchor tag using php regex from the given string if it's not inside of another tag.

Input:

```
Hi Hello <a href="#">World</a>. This is <div class="some">testing <a href="#">content</a>. some more content</div>
```

Output:

```
Hi Hello. This is <div class="some">testing <a href="#">content</a>. some more content</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the anchor tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this :

```php
$string = 'replace <a href="x">A</a> but not <div> <a>B</a> in tag </div> but also <a>C</a><div></div>';

echo preg_replace('/<a[^>]*?>([^<]*)<\/a>(?![^<]*<\/)/gi', '', $string);
```

A negative lookahead ensures that the anchor tag isn't followed by `</`.
Thus it's not enclosed by another tag.

The content of the tag is in capture group 1, incase you want to replace by `'\1'` instead of by `''`.

If it's about the div tags specifically then this one will ignore the div's :

```
echo preg_replace('/<div.*?>.*?<\/div>\K|<a[^>]*?>([^<]*)<\/a>/gi', '\1', $string);
```

Comment: Just a warning, This regex might help with the example you gave. But for more complex html it would also replace some anchors in a div with multiple anchors..

Comment: Imho recursion is needed [(example)](https://regex101.com/r/dR6yY5/1) but as you say for some input it might be convenient.

Comment: hi @LukStorms, I have similar question. How can remove the 'a' tag except inside of one class? eg.. 'a' tag should not removed if it is inside class 'tweet'(<div class="tweet">) else 'a' tag will be removed.

Comment: Perhaps with a negative lookbehind. Which isn't supported in javascript, but should be in the php regex flavor.  But it's a bit inflexible to use. For example `(?<!<div class="tweet"> )(<a[^>]*?>([^<]*)<\/a>)` would remove all anchors, enclosed or not. Except when it's proceeded by literally `<div class="tweet"> `. (not that the space matters). [regex101 test](https://regex101.com/r/pE2zH2/2).

Comment: Could also try this `(<div class="tweet">.*?<\/div>)|<a[^>]*?>([^<]*)<\/a>` and replace it by `\1\2`. It's with an OR. If it's a tweet div it will get in capture group one, else the content of the tag gets in capture group one.  [regex101 test](https://regex101.com/r/sI8yT0/1)

Comment: hi @LukStorms, thank you very much for the valuable time. Using (?<!<div class="tweet"> )(<a[^>]*?>([^<]*)<\/a>) is working fine but it fails whend when  'a' is not proceeded by <div class="tweet">... eg.. <div class="tweet" id="ram"> testing <a href="#">Tweet</a> </div>

Comment: Yeah, cos that div got more then just the class. So the 2nd regex would need to be slightly modified : `(<div class="tweet".*?>.*?<\/div>)|<a[^>]*?>([^<]*)<\/a>`. With the look behind that's impossible because look behinds have issues with stuff like `.*`

Comment: Thanks. Last one. Apparently there's a \K switch that resets a match.  Which seems useful here. `preg_replace('/<div class="tweet".*?>.*?<\/div>\K|<a[^>]*?>([^<]*)<\/a>/gsi', '\1', $string);`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not a job for regex but also tried by use of a [common trick](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick) and [`(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#pcrevariation)

```
'~(<(?!a\b)(\w+)\b(?>(?:(?!</?\2\b).)+(?1)?)*</\2>)(*SKIP)(*F)|<a\b.*?</a>\s*~si'
```

- The first part before `(*SKIP)(*F)` matches and skips any tags that are [not](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `<a` [recursively](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html).
- The second part after pipe `|` is the part to be matched with optional [whitespace](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) at the end.
- [Flags](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) used: `s` (PCRE_DOTALL), `i` (PCRE_CASELESS)

[Try pattern at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gP6jU4/1) or see [eval.in for PHP Demo](https://eval.in/585963)

There are probably better solutions by use of [DOMDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571232/parse-html-with-phps-html-domdocument) or [other parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php).

Comment: First time I see those *SKIP and *FAIL verbs used.  Nice. I'll have to experiment with those a bit.